# C# Console Connect to On-premise sharepoint PNP Core

Tags: sharepoint, csom, pnp-core-sdk

I am using C# Console and trying to connect to an on-premise Sharepoint.  I was able to connect to it using CSOM without having to specify an authentication method.  I just assume it just used my active directory credentials or something similar.

But trying to use PNP core its forcing me to use an Authentication Method.  I tried using InteractiveAuthenticationProvider but that pops up a window and I want this console application to run without any interaction using the logged in session.

Any ideas?  Is this possible using PNP core?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using CSOM as I couldn't figure out to use PNP Core on premise.  From what I could tell PNP Core seems to be only compatible with the online sharepoint.